# How to fix nullpointerexception while locating element using selenium (POM, not pagefactory)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use POM class, getting Nullpointer exception. however if I use driver.findelement directly in class, it works correct. Can you please pour in your thougts to fix this?

```
@Test
public void testFlow() throws InterruptedException {
    UtilityClass.setUpPath();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    try{
        driver.navigate().to("http://demo.guru99.com/payment-gateway/check_credit_balance.php");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("card_nmuber")).sendKeys("1234567891234567");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("card_nmuber")).getAttribute("value"));
        HomePage hp = new HomePage(driver);
        hp.clickSubmit();
    }
    finally{
        driver.quit();
    }
}
public class HomePage {
WebDriver driver;

public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

@FindBy(name = "submit")
private WebElement signIn ;

public void clickSubmit() {
    signIn.click(); }} }}
```

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think you are not passing the driver to the constructor of the page. that explains the error. Happy learning !!!

Comment: @Sureshmani - Even after adding webdriver (edited the code above), still getting NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HomePage class:

```
By signIn = By.name("submit");
public void clickSubmit() {
driver.findElement(signIn).click(); }}
```

Found the correct way of using POM without Page factory. This is working code

Answer (score 2):

Your page object field is not associated with a `WebElement`. You need to add a constructor that would call

`PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)`

Your constructor of course has to take `WebDriver` as an argument